# Using an X509 certificate from an Azure Blob and using it in an Azure website

Tags: asp.net, azure, x509certificate2

I read another post about this, I try the answers but I am having errors running in azure, running locally it's OK.
I cant find the solution, to use a certificate.p12 from file.
I have the error in  ObjCert.Import(certData) when I run in Azure, not in local.
Thanks!

```
X509Certificate2 objCert = new X509Certificate2();


            string accountName = "xxxxxstorage";
            string accountKey = "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqjt8DGAI6aBoBzdwwwwwwwwwwwwwzZg==";



            StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
            CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("certificate");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Certificate.p12");
            byte[] certData;
            // Save blob contents to a memorystream.
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(stream);
                certData = stream.ToArray();
            }
            objCert.Import(certData);
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: In the CrypthographicException I have:

+  [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException] {Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.} System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

and in the CryptographicException.Message:
"The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

I solve it
Replacing:

```
objCert.Import(certData)
```

by

```
X509Certificate2 selfSignedCert = new X509Certificate2(certData, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```